# How can I set a different color for text and background of canvas HTML?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm using canvas to create a dynamic Wheel of fortune. Any time I add a new item, it recalculates the spaces evenly. I was able to make it happen using canvas.  I know that `canvas.fillStyle = somecolor;` sets the color I want to the slice that is being created.
I also wanted to put some text inside each slice. **However, I can't figure a way to make canvas draw a text with a different color from the color of the slice.** Is that even possible?

Here's what I'm doing

```
  const drawSlice = useCallback((deg: number, color: string, text:string) => {
    if (!canvasRef.current) {
        return;
      }
      const canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = canvasRef.current;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      const width = canvas.width;
      const center = width/2;
      const sliceDeg = 360 / wheelItems.length;

      if (ctx) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillText(text, center, deg2rad(deg));

        ctx.moveTo(center, center);
        ctx.arc(center, center, width / 2, deg2rad(deg), deg2rad(deg + sliceDeg));
        ctx.lineTo(center, center);
        ctx.fill();

      }
  },[wheelItems.length])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you might want to change `ctx.fillStyle` between the moment you draw the text and the moment you draw the slice.

```js
if (ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillText(text, center, deg2rad(deg));

    // here :
    ctx.fillStyle = color2;
    ctx.moveTo(center, center);
    ctx.arc(center, center, width / 2, deg2rad(deg), deg2rad(deg + sliceDeg));
    ctx.lineTo(center, center);
    ctx.fill();
}
```

You can change `ctx.fillStyle` whenever you want, as many times as you want.

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I noticed that the text using 'fillText' is a little bit blurry, any idea what could be causing it?

Comment: If your text is blurry, it is probably too small; try using a bigger/bolder font using `ctx.font = "18px sans-serif";` or `ctx.font = "bold 14px sans-serif";` before calling fillText.